# Operations on numeric strings with R

Tags: r, string

I would like do some basic operations on vector made of numeric strings

```
string<-c("1_3_4","3_5_5_1","4_2")
```

I would like to calculate the sum, mean, the greatest value and the smallest one for each string.

```
stringsum<-function (string)===> 8  14  6
stringmean<-function (string)===> 2.666667  3.5  3
stringSup<-fuction (srtring)===> 4  5  4
stringInf<-function (string)===> 1  1  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define a single small function that does the job of all 4 functions. It takes your character vector and any function you choose as its arguments. It extracts the numbers from each entry to produce a list of numeric vectors, then applies any function you choose to each vector in the list

```r
string_do <- function(s, func) {
  sapply(lapply(strsplit(s, "\\D"), as.numeric), func)
}
```

So you can do:

```r
string_do(string, sum)
#> [1]  8 14  6

string_do(string, mean)
#> [1] 2.666667 3.500000 3.000000

string_do(string, min)
#> [1] 1 1 2

string_do(string, max)
#> [1] 4 5 4
```